# Tools to improve C++ MFC code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tfsbuild, code-analysis, code-metrics

We have a number of large C++ MFC project that we manage. Unfortunately, the code quality in them not very good and there are no unit tests. I am therefore looking for tools that can help us to analyze and improve the code.

I am looking for tools for the following:

- Find duplicate code (there are a lot of such in the code)
- Find problem code based on software metrics
- Give suggestions on how the code can be improved
- Framework for Unit Tests (the development team has lite experience with unit testing and code is not written to allow such)

I would like that the tools can be used together with TFS Build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For  software metrics I recommend you give [cppdepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/) a try.
  It has a lot of code quality metrics and you can write your own. But I'm not sure if it has duplicate code detection.
  It should work with TFS - and can generate custom reports and has an evaluation you can use before purchasing.
- For unit testing you can either use the built in MSTest (for C++) support in Visual Studio 2012/2013 that has good Visual Studio & TFS integration although does not include a mocking framework.
- Another option is to use [GoogleMock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) (bundled with GoogleTest) that can be run (as executable during TFS build and can be run using [Google Test Runner](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9dd47c21-97a6-4369-b326-c562678066f0) (VS2012/2013)

If you want a good reference book for unit testing on C++ - take a look at [Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development](http://pragprog.com/book/lotdd/modern-c-programming-with-test-driven-development).